# Can I use the embedded nautilus-terminal in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, nautilus, nautilus-extensions

In previous versions of Ubuntu, I have used [nautilus-terminal](http://projects.flogisoft.com/nautilus-terminal/) which embeds a terminal into the nautilus window.

In Ubuntu 13.10, I have intalled `nautilus-terminal` using the usual steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flozz/flozz 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nautilus-terminal
```

I have restarted my computer, but there is nothing showing up in nautilus.  I have tried F4 as well as Ctrl+Shift+T, but neither bring nautilus-terminal into view.

I am using the default Files application that comes with it - 3.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `nautilus-python`, if you haven't already.

Comment: Already got `nautilus-python` but no nautilus terminal shows up unfortunately.